# Windows file in spark read csv

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, databricks

I am using databricks for a practice in Python

I am trying to load a windows file via:

```
diamonds = spark.read.csv('file:///C:/abc.csv', header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

I am sure that my file is in C:/abc.csv but the system always returns this error:

```
u'Path does not exist file:/C:/abc.csv;'
```

How can I load a file in windows system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Define full path as variable - every path should begin with a drive if local**

```
# remove the 'file' string and use 'r' or 'u' prefix to indicate raw/unicore string format
# Option 1
PATH = r'C:\abc.csv'  # raw string
# Option 2
PATH = u'C:\\abc.csv' # unicode string
```

**2. Set the path variable to your spark call**

```
diamonds = spark.read.csv(PATH, header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

In essence, your filepath is wrong.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: PATH = u"C:\abc.csv" 
print PATH

Comment: C:bc.csv     I proved with: PATH = u"C:\\abc.csv" , in this case PRINT is correct: C:\abc.csv but system generate a error message: IllegalArgumentException: u'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Cabc.csv'

Answer (score 0):

Databricks is a cloud service that runs a cluster in the cloud. You can interact with the cluster using a notebook in your browser, but databricks doesn't have access to files on your computer. (Allowing websites to access arbitrary files on your computer would be a huge security issue. Image if I sent you a malicious link, and when you clicked it I could just read any file on your computer).

If you use the data button on the left side of the databricks UI, you can upload csv files and create tables that will be available tp your databricks cluster.